# Comparison method violates its general contract even though Double.compare(v1, v2) is used

Tags: java, sorting, exception, collections, comparator

First of all: I know, this question is answered in numerous places on stack overflow, however, this question is different. I'm not trying to make my own comparison, I'm using Double.compare() to compare 2 doubles.

So, the Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at repository.corpus.document.Summarizer.summarize(Summarizer.java:53)
at muse.GATrainer.RougeNEvaluator.getFitness(RougeNEvaluator.java:63)
at muse.GATrainer.RougeNEvaluator.getFitness(RougeNEvaluator.java:1)
at org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.FitnessEvalutationTask.call(FitnessEvalutationTask.java:52)
at org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.FitnessEvalutationTask.call(FitnessEvalutationTask.java:26)
... 4 more
```

the code:

```
List<Sentence> sentenceList = finalRepresentation.getSentences();
Comparator<Sentence> scoreComperator = new Comparator<Sentence>()
{
    public int compare(Sentence o1, Sentence o2)
    {
    if (o1.equals(o2))
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to compare a sentence to it self");
    }       

    if (Double.isInfinite(o1.getScore()) || Double.isNaN(o1.getScore()))
    {
        System.out.println(o1.getSentence() + " score " + o1.getScore());
    }
    if (Double.isInfinite(o2.getScore()) || Double.isNaN(o2.getScore()))
    {
        System.out.println(o2.getSentence() + " score " + o2.getScore());
    }

    return Double.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore());
    }
};

Collections.sort(sentenceList, Collections.reverseOrder(scoreComperator)); // source of the exception
```

this is the sentence class code (the parts of it concerning the score):

```
public class Sentence implements Comparable<Sentence>
{
// ...
private double score = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // the final score of the sentence will be saved here later
// ...
public double getScore()
{
    return score;
}

public void setScore(double score)
{
    this.score = score;
}
// ..
}
```

at this [link](http://pastebin.com/qKnxEZzS) you could find some scores that I've printed out in the comparator (I've added a syso that printed out o1 and o2 get sentences)

Note: the field score IS initiated to Double.MIN_VALUE, and as you see in the code I've tested it for extreme points (NaN and Infinity). The test in the comparator doesn't print anything at the console, hence I suppose the scores are neither NaN nor Infinity. Maybe I'm mistaken.

I would appropriate some ideas.

Comment: This could happen if `setScore` is called concurrently with sorting.

Comment: What are you getting from `getScore()`?

Comment: Can you show us some input of scores? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: You're getting the score more than once so the `double` you check for finiteness and NaN-ness might not be the same one you're comparing.  Is it always the case that `x.getScore() == x.getScore() || isNaN(x.getScore()) && isNaN(x.getScore())` for any given `x`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem and find out which instances (scores/strings) are involved when the error occurs?

Comment: sure, I've attached some http://pastebin.com/qKnxEZzS

Comment: @koljaTM This problem is self-reproduced every time I run the program.  I don't know what input causes the problem.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I didn't understand your question. Are implying that a race condition could potentially be the cause of this problem?

Comment: @MikeSamuel please write your comment as an answer since you were right and a synchronization of the data at the critical section (the score variable it self) Because I used the texts as data to train the model and it constantly changed the score which actually broke the contract. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to override equals() as well so that it corresponds to your compareTo() method? Remember, if compareTo==0 the objects have to be equals()

Comment: That wouldn't *violate* the general contract of `compare`. Also note that `TimSort` never calls `equals`.

Comment: I'm using an external comparator, I don't think it should be using equals, however, just for the sake of argument - the equals method is implemented as well. However, the internal compareTo() method and equals() method compare the Sentence class by the sentence string using the String.compareTo and String.equals methods. I need to sort the array by the score of each sentence and later by ID which differ from the internal compare and equals method.

Comment: so can it happen that two sentences have the same string but different scores?

Comment: this can not happen, however just for the sake of argument I'll add a check in the comparator for same instance.